# Rails unable to display all the data in my index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display all data in my Index.html.erb as shown below

```
S.no   name        place       logo      rating   rank
1      apple         usa                   34       1
2       dell         usa                   46       1
3       hcl          usa                    nil     nil
```

But I am Only able to display  rated companies that is only first 2 companies but I want to display all the data but unrated should be displayed in bottom of the table. How can I do that.

This my controller action I am using to it.

```
def index

    @companies = CompanyRating.select('company_id,avg(satisfaction+work_environment+cd) as rating, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id,company_id)) as rank').group('company_id').order('rank') 

  end
```

Please help to solve it.

Comment: check adding multiple order like
.order("rank DESC, rating ASC")

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def index
  count = CompanyRating.count      
  @companies = CompanyRating.select('company_id,avg(satisfaction+work_environment+cd) as rating, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id,company_id)) as rank').group('company_id').order("coalesce(rank, #{count}) ASC")
end
```

Comment: I am getting the following error.PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "rank"
LINE 1: ..._ratings"  GROUP BY company_id  ORDER BY coalesce('rank', 12..